# Count total number of digits from a given positive number without looping in C

Tags: c

How to count total number of digits from a given positive number without looping in C?

Comment: This is such a homeworky question (especially the "without using construct" part) that you had better explain why you want to do this at all. Is it homework? an interview question? And lastly, in what base?

Comment: If you cannot use loops, can you use maths? How about recursion? Also, if this question is homework, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: What kind of number? double, float, 32 bit integer? signed or unsigned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For integers, take the log10 of the number, round down, and add one.

**TEST:**

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int 
num_digits(unsigned long number)
{
    return (int)(floor(log10((double)number)) + 1.0);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned long test_numbers[] = {
        1, 9, 10, 99, 100, 999, 1000, 9999, 10000, 99999, 100000, 999999,
        123456789ul,
        999999999ul,
        0
    };

    unsigned long *ptr;
    for(ptr = test_numbers; *ptr; ptr++)
    {
        printf("Number of digits in %lu: %d\n", *ptr, num_digits(*ptr));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Number of digits in 1: 1
Number of digits in 9: 1
Number of digits in 10: 2
Number of digits in 99: 2
Number of digits in 100: 3
Number of digits in 999: 3
Number of digits in 1000: 4
Number of digits in 9999: 4
Number of digits in 10000: 5
Number of digits in 99999: 5
Number of digits in 100000: 6
Number of digits in 999999: 6
Number of digits in 123456789: 9
Number of digits in 999999999: 9
```

Comment: Are you sure this is precise enough, and doesn't give the wrong answer for some 999... number?

Comment: @starblue: you can't be entirely sure based on the C standard, since it doesn't specify the accuracy of log functions or the widths of types. However, if the "given positive number" is a 32 bit integer, and the log is done in an IEEE double, then the *precision* is good enough. The *accuracy* may not be.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solutions, assuming 16-bit integer values and logical expressions evaluating to 0 or 1.  You could replace the conditions with `(u > 99) ? 1 : 0` if you're worried about portability.

```
int digits( unsigned u)
{
    return 1 + (u > 9) + (u > 99) + (u > 999) + (u > 9999);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions for you!

```
int digit_count(unsigned int n)
{
   if (n < 10)
      return 1;
   else
      return (1 + digit_count(n / 10));
}
```

and

```
   unsigned int n = 50;
   int i = 0;

HACK:
   i++;

   if (n < 10)
   {
      printf("Digits: %d\n", i);
   }
   else
   {
      n /= 10;

      goto HACK;
   }
```

Don't hate me for the last one :(

Comment: "Without looping" should include the use of "goto". Now you are hated by everyone ;-)

Comment: Well, "goto" can be used for multiple things, including but not limited to loops ;)

Comment: GOTO is evil, but I like the use of 'HACK'.

Comment: Technically speaking, so does the first one - recursion is mathematically equivalent to looping. It all depends on what definition of "looping" you want to use. Is it just while/do-while/for? Or is it any construct that repeats an action if a sentinel case has not yet been met?

Comment: @Shravan: that's exactly the reason WHY I called it "HACK" :) - @Wayne Werner - because OP wasn't clear enough, I just thought he was meant to avoid the typical "while", "for", ... :)

Answer (score 0):

`return snprintf(0, 0, "%d", num);`